# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Unable to enable the Cordova geolocation control in the Mobile Browser Simulator

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-mbs

running WL Studio 6.0, on RHEL 6, with Firefox.

I am unable to enable the Cordova geolocation control in the Mobile Browser Simulator.  When I expand the Geolocation section in Cordova controls, all I get is the following message within the control:

> "Using the geolocation service provided with Firefox."

I have turned off Firefox's "geo.enabled" config setting in about:config, reloaded the page, restarted the browser.

I have set Firefox's Share Location permission to blocked in my page settings for the MBS page and reloaded the browser.

Is there a way to enable this MBS feature on firefox (on linux)?

Comment: Moving to Chromium, using install instrs found here: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2013/install-chromium-on-centos-red-hat-rhel/  == moderate success.  enabling java and iced tea always in Chromium about:plugins, adding `%URL% --no-sandbox` to the eclipse web browser config parameter field for the chromium entry has the MBS launching, cordova controls operating, nothing hanging so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting in the Mobile Browser Simulator to change that, but sounds like there should be. Or at least needs to better detect if the FireFox geo.enabled setting is turned on.